# How much long period azure blobs can be archived?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-storage, blobstore

I would like to archived the blobs. But not able to find the official period till when it will be archived (Max period of archival).Is it long life archived or will be deleted after some years ?

Comment: *would like to achieved the blobs. * ? I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I don't think Azure would ever delete blobs unless you configured a time-to-live on them.

Comment: @PeterBons Sorry its spelling mistake. I would like to know the maximum period of blob archival  in years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no maximum archival duration for a blob, with no limit mentioned in the documentation either.

You can archive a blob for as long as you like, virtually unlimited.